# Method reference does not compile - Integer::new

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference

Why does this not compile?

```
Stream.generate(Integer::new(1)).limit(10);
```

It gives the error

> Syntax error on token "new", AssignmentOperator expected after this token

Sure, I could rewrite this expression to

```
Stream.generate(() -> new Integer(1)).limit(10);
```

but I want to know the reason why the first statement is failing...

Comment: You can’t provide additional arguments to method references. So you have to use a lambda expression instead. But using `Integer`’s constructor is nonsensical anyway. You can use `Stream.generate( () -> 1)`…

Comment: Because `Integer::new(1)` is not a valid method/constructor reference. [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't pass arguments to method references explicitly. They can only be passed implicitly.

For example, if you have an `IntStream`, you can `mapToObj` it to `Integer` instances using a method reference of the `public Integer(int value)` constructor :

```
IntStream.of(1,1,1).mapToObj(Integer::new)...
```

Of course, using the `public Integer(int value)` constructor for small `int` values is usually a bad idea, since it may result in the creation of unnecessary multiple instances all having the same `int` value, instead of taking advantage of the `IntegerCache`, which caches `Integer` instances of small values (-128 to 127).

Comment: Or `IntStream.of(1,1,1).boxed()` to avoid obsolete instance creations…

Comment: @Holger Yes, I never said this code makes any sense. I only demonstrated how the `Integer(int)` constructor can be invoked using a method reference.

Comment: I’d say that using either, autoboxing or explicit `Integer.valueOf`, should be the preferred way, regardless of the actual `int` value. It’s true that only small values are guaranteed to be cached, but that doesn’t preclude the others from being cached and using the factory also documents that the developer makes no assumptions about the object identity, in other words, generally allows caching, whether it will happen or not. Even JVM-side optimizations are possible, as the JVM knows about this method.